# array,pointer address value confusion

Tags: c, pointers

in running the code below , i got this output

```
num= 2359120, addr of num=2359120, *num=10,addr of num[0]=2359120
```

I can't comprehend how num and &num have the same value. any help, please? i know that the name of an array is a pointer itself

```
#include <math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int num[]={10,20,30,40,50};
printf("num= %d, addr of num=%d, *num=%d,addr of num[0]=%d\n",num,&num,*num,&num[0]);
}
```

Comment: Closing as duplicate, downvoting for poor research prior to posting question.

Answer (score 0):

name of array `num` is same as the address of the array `&num` which is same as the address of the first element `&num[0]` and hence, your output.